# Преобразователь ссылок php

Tags: php, ссылки

Помогите пожалуйста. Имею значение $message где есть ссылка. Надо чтобы в выводе она была кликабильна (не site.ru, а <a href=site.ru>site.ru</a>. Старый который есть не сохраняет части ссылки после знака &, и почему-то делает кликабельным пол чата :(

Дайте пожалуйста кто-нибудь функцию хорошего преобразователя пассивных ссылок в активные

Comment: function links($message){
  return preg_replace('%((?:http|ftp)://[-\w]+(?:\.[-\w]+)+\b[-\w:@?=&+,!/~*$\.\'\%]*)(?<![\.,?!)])%i',"<a href=\"\\1\">\\1<a>",$message);
}
Вот это сейчас стоит и вместо http://site.ru/?a=1&b=2 делает http://site.ru/?a=1&;b=2

Answer (score 3):

В простейшем случае это будет выглядеть примерно так

```
$message="tetstsdtts http://afsfs.dsgddfgfd";
$message=preg_replace('/((http|ftp|telnet|gopher):\/\/[^ \n$]+)/iu', '<A href="\\1">\\1</A>', $message);
echo $message;
```

Поиск происходит по принципу: от названия протокола http:// ftp:// telnet:// gopher:// до пробела, перевода строки или конца строки. Для большинства нужд мне кажется этого достаточно.

Comment: Русский текст улетает

Comment: Было: Вася я пошёл на сайт http://site.ru :D Стало: http://site.ru :D

Comment: @GeneralProger, а Вы проверяли? :) В регулярке нет вообще никаких отсылок на конкретный язык :)
    
    $message="tetstsdtts http://президент.рф ";
    $message=preg_replace('/((http|ftp|telnet|gopher):\/\/[^ \n$]+)/iu', '<A href="\\1">\\1</A>', $message);
    echo $message;

Comment: Проверил, сейчас ещё раз проверю

Comment: @GeneralProger, проверьте языки Вашего скрипта (например что кодировка скрипта совпадает с кодировкой выдачи сервером). Копайте в сторону ошибок на Вашей стороне с кодировками. Регулярка верна.

Comment: К сожалению сообщение выходит пустое :(

Comment: Я кстати добавил модификатор iu что означает работу с Unicode, если Ваш сайт в кодировке cp1251, то я порекомендую перейти к UTF-8 и в крайнем случае исправить регулярное выражение на /((http|ftp|telnet|gopher):\/\/[^ \n$]+)/i без u

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция  eregi_replace(). Осуществляет замену по регулярному выражению
Примерно это выглядит так.

```
ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]",
                 "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $messenge);
```

Comment: Русский текст улетел в трубу